# How is the data size of a MongoDB Atlas cluster calculated: document size or storage size?

Tags: mongodb, storage

[MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) hosts MongoDB in the cloud, and has various sizes that you can select, like 2GB, 5GB, 10GB, etc.

It's not clear to me which data size is applicable: in my case I have a database with a document size of 1.6 GB, and a storage size of about 0.5 GB (since the documents are zipped when stored).

Are the size limits of MongoDB Atlas referring to the *document size* of your database or the *storage size*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the hard way that the size limit is the **document size** (uncompressed size), not the size on disk.

So for a database with 1.6 GB document size and 0.5 GB disk size, I need a 2 GB plan on MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: Which Atlas product did you choose ? There is no 1GB storage option in MongoDB Atlas for all providers (AWS, Azure and GCP). The minimum storage is 2GB (AWS and Azure).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, there is indeed no 1 GB plan at MongoDB Atlas, it was just to try to make my point clear like would it fit a 1 GB database having a document size of 1.6 GB and storage size of 0.5 GB. Because it's the document size I need at least 2 GB, even if there would be an 1 GB plan.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation,

> Atlas calculates the storage limit for shared clusters based on data
>   usage, as opposed to the **storageSize** metric used by non-shared
>   clusters (which includes compression). Atlas determines data usage by
>   summing a cluster’s **dataSize** and **indexSize**.

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/faq/#how-does-atlas-calculate-storage-limits-for-shared-clusters-m0-m2-m5

Answer (score 1):

The cluster disk space used is the `fsUsedSize` from `db.stats()`

It is not `dataSize` (as specified in the selected answer). However, its not exactly `storageSize` either.

My cluster has around 5GB of `dataSize` and the `fsUsedSize` is around 4GB while the `storageSize` is around 3GB. The ATLAS portal shows 4GB used.

Even in your normal standalone deployment, if you check the directory where the data files are stored, it will be considerably bigger than the `storageSize` but it will be also considerably less that the `dataSize`.
You will notice the mongo data directory's size is same as the `fsUsedSize`.

**So, my calculated guess would be** `storageSize` + some overhead (which can be in GBs).

In a nutshell, whatever the mongo data directory on your own deployment will consume.